# List child page IDs not using certain template

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to get an array of all wordpress child page IDs that are no using a certain template?

I know I can get the template with:

```
'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
'meta_value' => 'template.php'
```

and I expect I could use get_pages, but not sure how I can put the query together.

Comment: you want to restrict template??

Comment: tried looking for this in the admin dashboard?

Comment: The end result will be to display a list of all the child pages that are not using a certain template, but I only want to get a list of the IDs at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but is there a better way of doing it?

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $parent_ID,
    'post_type'   => 'page', 
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish' 
);
$children = get_children( $args );
$exclude_children = null;
foreach($children as $child) {
    $metadata = get_post_meta($child->ID);
    if($metadata['_wp_page_template'][0] == 'template.php') {
        $args = array(
            'post_parent' => $child->ID,
            'post_type'   => 'page', 
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish' 
        );
        $exclude_array = get_children( $args );
        foreach($exclude_array as $exclude) {
            $exclude_children .= $exclude->ID.',';
        }
    }
}
```